# Pass type as parameter to user defined mysql function

Tags: mysql

I want to write a CONVERT_MSSQL(Type, Data) function that swaps the parameters position of the MySQL CONVERT(Data, Type) function, in an effort to make sql server queries work on mysql without much effort.
The issue is that i don't know how to define:

- a function parameter that accepts a type.
- a function parameter having a generic (any) type.

the function i want to write would be of the following form:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CONVERT_MSSQL(Type_ TYPE, Data_ ANY)
  RETURN CONVERT(Data_, Type_)
```

Is it even possible ? Also Note that i can't automatically rewrite the queries by swapping parameters, there are dozens of queries which all have really complex, not easily parsable expressions in their Data_ parameter

Comment: Don't do this; just don't. There is no need to "reinvent the wheel".

Comment: I've also removed the SQL Server tag, as the answer you want is specifically for MySQL, not SQL Server; the question/answer you want has nothing to do with SQL Server itself (you just want to mimic its behaviour).

Comment: To add more to this, *every* dialect of SQL is different. You can't nor should expect that (blindly) copying SQL from one RDBMS to another will result in that SQL to run; for anything but the most basic of statements this is simply not true. If you have applications that use different RDBMS then you need to ensure you write SQL that is appropriate for the RDBMS *or* use syntax that you have tested works on all the ones you are using correctly. Obviously, as you add more different RDBMS in, the less transferable syntax you'll have.